# Eclipse Kepler SR2: The configured runtime is insufficient to provide an implementation for JAXB 2.2

Tags: eclipse, jaxb, facet

I'm running Eclipse Kepler SR2.  In Project Facets I have Java set to version 1.8 (the Java 8 patches are installed).  When I try to add the JAXB Facet at either version 2.1 or 2.2 and then click on "Further configuration required..." I have the following configured:

**Platform:  Generic JAXB 2.1 (or 2.2)**

**JAXB Implementation Type: JRE**

I get the error message:

**The configured runtime is insufficient to provide an implementation for JAXB 2.1 (or 2.2).**

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: You solved this? If so kindly share your solution.. getting the same in luna...

Comment: Perhaps.  If you recall, JAXB was recently added to the the JRE.  Before that, you needed a separate jar file on the classpath.  I'm thinking that the Eclipse project facet code has not been updated to reflect this, and thus rejects the selection of `JRE` for JAXB implementation on the `Further configuration available...` (Modify Faceted Project) page.  Instead, choose `Disable Library Configuration`.  This tells Eclipse that you will ensure the implementation is on the classpath, which of course it is (now being part of the JRE).

Comment: I have had the same issue on Eclipse Neon and I have solved it as mentioned by mbmast by choosing the option "Disable Library Configuration
"

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Mars : The configured runtime is insufficient to provide an implementation for JAXB2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639486/eclipse-mars-the-configured-runtime-is-insufficient-to-provide-an-implementati/44577255#44577255)

Try below steps.

```
     1) Select File->New ->Project
     2) Choose JAXB Project from JAXB and click Next
     3) Give Project Name and click Next
     4) On the next window, just Click Next
     5) On the next window (titled JAXB Facets), Choose "User Library" for JAXB implementation. 
        Click "Download Library.." picture and choose EclipseLink 2.5.2 
        (or the higher version shown in the window) and click Next
        This will install the library (make sure your are connected to internet.)
```

Comment: I can't endorse this solution as it loads the entire EclipseLink JPA implementation, which includes many, many support Jar files, including jaxb-core_2.2.11.v201407311112.jar, which is the one that resolves the issue discussed here.  As the original post is old now, I don't know if this has been resolved in Eclipse, but letting/telling Eclipse to use the version of JAXB now include in the JRE/JDK seems like the best solution to me.